# ZuulFallbackProvider not getting invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, hystrix

I am trying to have a fallback if Zuul does not find a service. I have the a ZuulSever with the below code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ZuulServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ZuulFallbackProvider fallBackProvider() {
        return new ZuulFallbackProvider() {

            @Override
            public ClientHttpResponse fallbackResponse() {

                return new ClientHttpResponse() {
                    @Override
                    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public InputStream getBody() throws IOException {
                        return new ByteArrayInputStream("Hello".getBytes());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getStatusText() throws IOException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return "Service Down";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public HttpStatus getStatusCode() throws IOException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return HttpStatus.OK;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getRawStatusCode() throws IOException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return 200;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void close() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public String getRoute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return "*";
            }

        };
    }
}
```

When the service in my route is up and running, I am able to get the output. But when I bring down the service in the route, I expected the fallback to kick in. But I still see an error message instead of the fallback message. Why is the fallback not invoked? I am using Dalston Release version.

Comment: Where is your `getRoute` method in ZuulFallbackProvider ? and which version are you using ?

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: What error message did you get from zuul ?

Comment: No specific error message from Zuul. The request just fails with 500 error, which would be the expected behavior if the fallback was not there.

Answer (score 2):

If you configure Zuul to directly connect to an URL for your route, it will use SimpleHostRoutingFilter, which will (almost) always return a 500 in case of an error. Any FallbackProviders will not kick in.

I used a custom SimpleHostRoutingFilter instead:

```
public class CustomErrorHostRoutingFilter extends SimpleHostRoutingFilter {
    public CustomErrorHostRoutingFilter(ProxyRequestHelper helper, ZuulProperties properties, ApacheHttpClientConnectionManagerFactory connectionManagerFactory, ApacheHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) {
        super(helper, properties, connectionManagerFactory, httpClientFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected ZuulException handleException(Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof ConnectTimeoutException) {
            return new ZuulException(ex, "Downstream timeout", HttpServletResponse.SC_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT, ex.getMessage());
        }

        if (ex instanceof IOException) {
            return new ZuulException(ex, "Downstream I/O error", HttpServletResponse.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, ex.getMessage());
        }

        return super.handleException(ex);
    }
}
```

Some kind of configuration class is required as well:

```
@Configuration
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ZuulConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SimpleHostRoutingFilter simpleHostRoutingFilter(ProxyRequestHelper helper,
                                                           ZuulProperties zuulProperties,
                                                           ApacheHttpClientConnectionManagerFactory connectionManagerFactory,
                                                           ApacheHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) {
        return new CustomErrorHostRoutingFilter(helper, zuulProperties, connectionManagerFactory, httpClientFactory);
    }
}
```